# Batch (Windows) alternative for Bash | tee -a log.txt

Tags: windows, batch-file, stdout

I need to get stdout echoed onto the command prompt and appended into a file.

I have tried echo "foo" | tee -a log.txt. I have looked on google, however these is nothing there that is relevant.

`"foo" | tee -a log.txt`

It should echo foo and append it to a file. Instead I get

```
'tee' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I don't want the command tee, I need to get stdout echoed onto the command prompt

Comment: You could have done a single search on here and would have found many [results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+tee)

Comment: In a great many situations, one is strongly discouranged from using software NOT provided in the windows installation.  Things such as `tee` or `tail`, etc.  A `tee` alternative that only uses Windows Cmd commands will be very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Pass what your trying into power shell, like this:
`powershell "echo foo | tee -a foo.txt"`